# sympy: Lambdify doesn't convert sqrt expression

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I try to lambdify some calculated eigenvalues but I get the following error.

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

To avoid a namespace clash (explained in this post [What causes this error (AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos') in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in)) I  used the following import command instead of `from sympy import *`

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

def calculate_general_eigenvalues():
    Y, Z = sp.symbols("Y,Z")
    Rzy = sp.symbols("Rzy", positive=True)

    eigenvalues = [Y + Z,Rzy*Y + sp.sqrt(Rzy*Z)]

    print("eigenvalues of the system ")
    print(eigenvalues[0])
    print(eigenvalues[1])
    lam1 = sp.lambdify((Y,Z), eigenvalues[0] ,modules=['numpy'])
    lam2 = sp.lambdify((Y,Z), eigenvalues[1] ,modules=["numpy", {'sqrt': np.sqrt}])
    print(lam1(1,1))
    print(lam2(1,1))


    return (lam1,lam2)


l1,l2 = calculate_general_eigenvalues()
```

I also found a second hint here ([Python: SymPy lambdify abs for use with NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610844/python-sympy-lambdify-abs-for-use-with-numpy)) were they include the command `lambdify(x, f(x), ["numpy", {'Abs': numpy.abs}])`  but it doesn't work in my code as you can see

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not sqrt. Your second eigenvalue involves Rzy which you did not include among the variables when lambdifying it. Fix that, and it will work simply with `modules="numpy"`. There is no need to remap sqrt: NumPy knows about sqrt, it just does not know how to apply it to a symbol such as Rzy.

```
lam1 = sp.lambdify((Y,Z), eigenvalues[0], modules='numpy')
lam2 = sp.lambdify((Y,Z,Rzy), eigenvalues[1], modules='numpy')
print(lam1(1,1))
print(lam2(1,1,1))
```